# How to rebase this branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

The image below consists of two parts:
*the first part* is the repository sample model, *the second part* is the repository state that I want to get using the git rebase.

I didn't forget anything in the second part. This is exactly what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the number of commits you want to manipulate is as small as in the picture : use `cherry-pick`

```
git checkout tmp1
# make sure you have a clean working directory before running reset --hard :
git reset --hard <e>
git cherry-pick <h> <i>
```

---

`git rebase` has a syntax to select a range of commits :

```
git checkout tmp1
# you need to mention <g>, the *parent* of the first commit you
# want to replay, not <h>
git rebase --onto <e> <g> tmp1

git checkout tmp2
git reset --hard <k>
git rebase --onto <e> <g> tmp2
```

---

a note about `git reset --hard` :

`git reset --hard <target>` is one of the few dangerous git commands, that can delete modifications from your disk without saving them somewhere first.

It sets the active commit to `<target>`, *and discards any modifications on all tracked files* (that's the dangerous part).

You should at least know the effects before using it.

Some easy ways to avoid loosing your un-committed work are :

- `git stash` your work before using `git reset --hard`,
- commit your work before using it (even after a `git reset`, the commit will still be available through `git reflog`),

Comment: Thanks. And also explain please what do you mean in `# make sure you have a clean working directory before running reset --hard`? What can happen here?

Comment: And also can I 1) `rebase` without checking out them? or 2) rebase the both at the same time, **not** rebasing them **separately**?

Comment: And also rebasing the tmp2 should I  use `git rebase --onto <e> <g> tmp2~1` to get the state as on the second picture?

Comment: And I also did the `git branch -D tmp2` to get the same think as on the picture

Comment: If you use a named branch as the 3rd parameter to `git rebase --onto 1 2 3`, it will move the branch after rebasing. If you use something that is not a branch name (for example : `tmp2~1`, which resolves to "the hash of tmp2's parent commit"), it will build the commits, and leave the repo in a "detached HEAD" state ; you will have to choose what to do with your branches. You may have to re-create your `tmp2` branch : `git branch tmp2`

Answer (score 5):

In that situation I'd choose to just rebuild branches rather than wandering into ninja rebase attempts :

```
git checkout -b new-tmp1 master
git cherry-pick h i
git checkout -b new-tmp2 master
git cherry-pick j k
```

Then if `new-tmp1` and `new-tmp2` suit your needs, just move old refs :

```
git branch -f tmp1 new-tmp1
git branch -f tmp2 new-tmp2
```

Comment: Thanks. And also could you tell me how does the `git checkout` work **with -b and two branch names**?

Comment: `-b` asks git to create a new branch then checking it out. First parameter is the name for the new branch, second parameter tells git where this new branch should be pointing at upon creation.